# C# Set length of string before assign to and add spaces in remaining place

Tags: c#, string

I need function or idea how to set length regardless of the length assigned to it and add spaces in remaining place, like this:

```
string s = "Example   ";
string s = "Exam      ";
```

Both got 10 letters length.

Comment: The `String` class contains bunch of methods. Paying efforts in searching might help you.

Comment: I found that function but thought it work like just add spaces to string. Well, maybe someone will have a similar problem like me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String.PadRight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string example1 = "Example".PadRight(10);  // "Example   "
string example2 = "Exam".PadRight(10);     // "Exam      "
```

Comment: @Nitze You don't have to create an intermediate string either, `string s = "Example".PadRight(10);` is perfectly valid.